# How to send slash commands from a user to a bot using Python

Tags: python, discord

This is my program:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'content': '/help'
}

header = {
    'authorization': '...'
}

r = requests.post('...', data= payload, headers=header)
```

I am trying to post a slash command to Discord using requests, but when I run the program the `/help` message shows up on the channel instead of activating the bot which is on the server.